# still in the majority

Tags: meaning, idioms

> "...they are of little interest to scholars of Sufi texts, such as W.C or A.S, who are, as far as we can tell, **still in the majority**."

1) In this sentence I have difficulty in understanding the term "still in the majority"

2) Would this stand for an idiom with a specific attribution?

Comment: It's not an idiom.  All of the words have their dictionary definitions (although I realize that *still* has many meanings): they *remain part of the majority*.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an idiom. All of the words have their dictionary definitions (although I realize that still has many meanings):

> they [W.C and A.S] remain part of the majority [opinion about these texts].

– stangdon